# Windows Runtime Component C++ Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use Windows Runtime ComponenT, i want to run C++ in Windows Phone 8 C#.

I can return Integers, double, float, booleans, but no char string or use void functions. I am receiving this when building the solution:

Error 3 error C3992: 'getChar': signature of public member contains invalid type 'char'

I can create void functions and it compiles but i can not use it in my C# code.

Also i would like to create objects in C++ and use it in the Windows Phone 8.

i don't know if my question is clear but i hope someone understand what i want to do and thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do but there are only certain types that are supported in C++/CX

See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755822.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700121.aspx